# JQ - How to remove quotes from keys

Tags: json, bash, shell, parsing, jq

I'm using JQ to render some JSON. Everything is fine but what I need though is output without keys quotes. Trying to use raw options but this not helps at all.

The script:

`jq --raw-output --arg ID "$ID" '[.articles[] | { ...`

output:

```
[
  {
    "id": "20191022203822",
    "title": "How tech companies measure “legal”",
```

What i need is:

```
[
  {
    id: "20191022203822",
    title: "How tech companies measure “legal”",
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: That's not valid json. I fear there's no other option than to load the json into a language that can parse it and output it yourself in any format you like.

Comment: Well, some can read it as a string, not a name/key.

Comment: every JSON compliant utility would output a whole JSON following JSON syntax, whereas you wanted a non-JSON output. I guess your best bet is to run it through `sed` where you drop the quotes from the label (but that approach is prone to false-positives), like: **`jq ... | sed -E 's/(^ +)"([^"]+)":/\1\2:/'`**

Comment: @Dmitry Dude, you made my day, please add is as an answer.

Comment: Some programs such as mongo collection configurations or certain javascript dictionary formats accept json like objects where the keys are missing quotes. In case anyone was wondering why we would want an easy way to generate non-compliant json like objects.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

adding my comment to the answer, as per request from OP:

every JSON compliant utility would output a whole JSON following JSON syntax, whereas you wanted a non-JSON output. I guess your best bet is to run it through `sed` where you drop the quotes from the label (but that approach is prone to false-positives):

```
jq ... | sed -E 's/(^ *)"([^"]*)":/\1\2:/'
```

(note, I changed `+` regex quantifiers into `*` to match universally on empty labels and zero indention as well)

Answer (score 2):

jq is Turing-complete so it's just a question of how easy it would be to get jq to produce non-JSON output.

In the present case, one could start with a recursive definition:

```
def printObject(offset):
  (offset * " " // "") as $offset
  | reduce to_entries[] as $kv ("";
      ($kv.value
       | if type == "string" then "\"\(.)\""
         elif type == "object" then printObject(offset+2)
         else . end) as $v
      | . + $offset  +  "  \($kv.key): \($v)\n")
  | "{\n" + . + $offset + "}";
```

With this definition,

```
{a:1, b:"etc", c: {d: [1,2,3]} } | printObject(0)
```

produces:

```
{
  a: 1,
  b: "etc",
  c: {
    d: [1,2,3]
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious, does jq handle recursive calls? your code snippet is limited only to flat objects, what about nested?

Comment: quite impressive! :)

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Dmitry's answer, since special characters still need to be quoted in keys, I found adjusting to add some of the special characters to be helpful:

```
jq ... | sed -E 's/(^ *)"([^".:-]*)":/\1\2:/'
```